# console.log no aparece con pm2

Tags: nodejs, parse.com

Tengo una app node.js de Parse Server donde necesito utilizar console.log para debugear el cloud code, el problema es que lanzando la app así:

```
node index.js
```

el log aparece, pero si lo lanzo con pm2:

```
pm2 start index.js
```

no aparecen los los logs de console.log pero si aparecen los logs nativos de parse, (en el caso anterior salen ambos)

Alguna idea? Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de iniciada la aplicación:

```
pm2 logs <app-name>
```

Todos los detalles en [la documentación](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/).

Comment: También puedes hacer solamente *pm2 logs* y te mostrará los logs de todas las apps corriendo